# Able to make phone calls from a custom Google Home/Google Assistant Action?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Is there a way to initiate a phone call from a custom Dialogflow action on the Google Home?  I'm setting up an Agent to get info about businesses, and I'd like to be able to have the user make a call to a business from my Action.

Answer (score 3):

Users can make phone calls as a built in functionality in the assistant.

At the moment, you can't initiate a call from your own Action on Google because there is no API that expose it.